# Spring - the views context change when I use a nested mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created my controller with spring like this:

```
@Controller
public class ProdutosController {

  @RequestMapping("produtos/form")
  public String form() {        
    return "produtos\\form";
  }
}
```

Everytime that I try access it returns:

```
-type Status report
-message /casadocodigo/produtos/WEB-INF/views/produtos/form.jsp
-description The requested resource is not available.
```

It adds an "produtos/" before the WEB-INF folder, but when I change my view to:

```
@RequestMapping("/form")
   public String form() {       
     return "produtos\\form";
}
```

It returns the correct path to my view.

Here my configuration classes:

```
public class ServletSpringMVC  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppWebConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }




@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={HomeController.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I know if I create the same directory structure it will eventually work, but everytime that I map something with a nested uri I will have to create a new folder inside my webapp folder. Is there any way to solve this?

I found the problem. There was a "/" missing in the view resolver. Now the class look like this:

```
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487228/3850595 i think you search     `<property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />`